# Django Database structure, How to handle slug from two different models like Facebook does?

Tags: django, database, django-models, uml

I have a project that publishes job offers, a job seeker can create a profile on the website and his profile page will have URL like:
    `www.domain_name.com/slug`

An institution publishing job offers can also create an account.The person actually creates the institution account will be considered as the administrator of the institution page, so he will have an account (*instance of UserProfile() and can add other members (*Users on the platform not affected to any institutions*) to that institution. Institution profile URL will be `www.domain_name.com/institution_slug`

Members will have their own UserProfile instance linked to that institution, and once connected, only the institution page data/functionalities will be visible, they will work as the institution.

So **What is the best way to have these 2 models and handle the URL pattern properly?** like

**urls.py**

```
path("<slug:slug>",profile,name='profile')
```

**views.py**

```
def profile(request,slug):
    user = UserProfile.objects.get(slug=slug) #get_object_or_404
    inst = Institution.objects.get(slug=slug) #get_object_or_404
```

In above example, I don’t want to have to query twice in two different models. Is there another way to do it? Or If I need to re-design the database structure, let me know!

**models.py**

```
UserProfile(models):
   # info_about_user
   sug = models.SlugField()
   institution = models.ForeignKey(Institution)

Institution(models.Model):
   # info_about_instituion
   slug = models.SlugField()
```

> Note that both may publish job offers:

```
Job(models.Model)
    owner = UserProfile or Institution
```

Comment: Making a design (or change an existing one) depends on a lot of constraints only an architect on site can know. Frankly, there are dozens of ways to implement the above sketch.

Comment: [*there are dozens of ways to implement the above sketch*] happy to know that. can you just show me one way, the easiest you think???

Comment: No. Because I'm not the architect and I don't know the constraints.